# Change span text on a click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link with image

```
<div class="va-pickers">
    <a class="va-picker"  data-attribute="pa_Attribute">
        <img class="va-picker-item"  src="img.jpeg">
    </a>
</div>
```

And I want to change span text ( change it ) on link click

```
<ul class="gform" id="gform_1">
    <li id="field_1">
        <div class="ginput_container">
            <div class="medium" id="s2id_input_1_2">
                <a class="select2-choice">
                    <span class="select2-chosen" id="select27">change it</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[data-attribute='pa_Attribute']").click(function(){
        $('#gform_1').find('span').text('my_text');
    });
});
```

But it doesn`t work

Thanks

Comment: It works here -> https://jsfiddle.net/p0creche/

Comment: The code works. Do you have enabled javascript and properly loaded jQuery library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works find. Check in your console to see if nothing is missing (JQuery maybe). [Here's your working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L6cykvLd/).

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
```